# How to order a column alphabetically in table using links and Get using PHP and MySQL?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a table. In the table, there is the headings customerID, name, city, address. They are in the top of of the table and they are links to the same page.

What I want to do is that, if I press Name in the table, it will put all the names in the column in order; same with customerID, if I press the link it will order all the numbers in the column.

I was hoping you guys would help.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    $options = array(
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND=> 'SET NAMES utf8',
    );
    $dsn        = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=name';
    $password   = 'pass';
    $username   = 'name';
    $db         = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);

    $query  = "SELECT";
    $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();

    echo "<table border=2>";
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th><a href="mypage.php?sort=customerid">Customer ID:      </a></th>";
        echo "<th><a href="mypage.php?sort=name">Name:</a></th>";
        echo "<th><a href="mypage.php?sort=city">City:</a></th>";
        echo "<th><a href="mypage.php?sort=address">Address:</a>     </th>";
    echo "</tr>";

    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        echo "<tr>";
            $customerid     =$row['customerid'];
            $name           =$row['name'];
            $city           =$row['city'];
            $address        =$row['address'];

            echo "<td>Customer ID: $customerid</td>"; 
            echo "<td>$name</td>";
            echo "<td>$city</td>";
            echo "<td>$address</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }   
    echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: What you're looking for is the `ORDER BY` clause in your query on the press of your button.

Comment: @Adrian Like this you mean ??     $query  = "SELECT";

if ($_POST['sort'] == 'customerid')
{
    $query .= " ORDER BY customerid";
}
elseif ($_POST['sort'] == 'name')
{
    $query .= " ORDER BY name";
}
elseif ($_POST['sort'] == 'city')
{
    $query .= " ORDER BY city";
}
elseif($_POST['sort'] == 'address')
{
    $query .= " ORDER BY address";
}
    $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this added:

```
if(isset($_GET['sort'])){
    $sort = $_GET['sort'];
}

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM myTable ORDER BY :sort");
```